# How do I detect if a Spark DataFrame has a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

When I create a `DataFrame` from a JSON file in Spark SQL, how can I tell if a given column exists before calling `.select`

Example JSON schema:

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": 1,
    "c": 2
  }
}
```

This is what I want to do:

```scala
potential_columns = Seq("b", "c", "d")
df = sqlContext.read.json(filename)
potential_columns.map(column => if(df.hasColumn(column)) df.select(s"a.$column"))
```

but I can't find a good function for `hasColumn`. The closest I've gotten is to test if the column is in this somewhat awkward array:

```
scala> df.select("a.*").columns
res17: Array[String] = Array(b, c)
```

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Just assume it exists and let it fail with `Try`. Plain and simple and supports an arbitrary nesting:

```
import scala.util.Try
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def hasColumn(df: DataFrame, path: String) = Try(df(path)).isSuccess

val df = sqlContext.read.json(sc.parallelize(
  """{"foo": [{"bar": {"foobar": 3}}]}""" :: Nil))

hasColumn(df, "foobar")
// Boolean = false

hasColumn(df, "foo")
// Boolean = true

hasColumn(df, "foo.bar")
// Boolean = true

hasColumn(df, "foo.bar.foobar")
// Boolean = true

hasColumn(df, "foo.bar.foobaz")
// Boolean = false
```

Or even simpler:

```
val columns = Seq(
  "foobar", "foo", "foo.bar", "foo.bar.foobar", "foo.bar.foobaz")

columns.flatMap(c => Try(df(c)).toOption)
// Seq[org.apache.spark.sql.Column] = List(
//   foo, foo.bar AS bar#12, foo.bar.foobar AS foobar#13)
```

Python equivalent:

```py
from pyspark.sql.utils import AnalysisException
from pyspark.sql import Row


def has_column(df, col):
    try:
        df[col]
        return True
    except AnalysisException:
        return False

df = sc.parallelize([Row(foo=[Row(bar=Row(foobar=3))])]).toDF()

has_column(df, "foobar")
## False

has_column(df, "foo")
## True

has_column(df, "foo.bar")
## True

has_column(df, "foo.bar.foobar")
## True

has_column(df, "foo.bar.foobaz")
## False
```

Comment: This works with structured field as well. The solutions that uses `contains` function does not! +1

Comment: On first glance the `df(path)`  or `df[col]` looks like it would be a very costly test but this is all lazy dag building so it's cheap, is that correct?

Comment: @Davos That has little to do with laziness. `Columns` are not data containers, but components of query description model. In broader context to know anything about `Dataset` you have process and check its logical `QueryExectution.analyzed` plan, that applies to `col` / `apply` (both `resolve`) or `schema` / `columns` alike.

Comment: @10465355saysReinstateMonica Thanks that's exactly what I meant. I am not referring to `lazy` directives in Scala but rather the phased approach of how Spark creates a logical plan, transforms it to a physical plan and then executes the tasks on the cluster. If this is _resolved_ at the logical plan stage then it's cheap.

Comment: @zero323 The python equivalent does not work on struct columns which are inside an array.
e.g. 
'{ "name": "test", "address":[{"houseNumber":"1234"}]}'

should df.select be used instead of  df[col]

Comment: @zero323 how will you check of nested array.. in df(path)  it does not accept array elements like property[0].property[1].number..

Answer (score 74):

Another option which I normally use is

```
df.columns.contains("column-name-to-check")
```

This returns a boolean

Comment: Yes that's correct it doesn't work with nested columns.

Comment: Try:: 

df.columns.__contains__("column-name-to-check")

Comment: df.columns.__contains__("column-name-to-check") works.

Comment: This is partially incorrect, as the output from df.columns is a list
`type(df.columns)` returns `<class 'list'>`

and list don't have a 'contains' attribute.

`'col_to_check' in df.columns` is fine

Answer (score 13):

Actually you don't even need to call select in order to use columns, you can just call it on the dataframe itself

```
// define test data
case class Test(a: Int, b: Int)
val testList = List(Test(1,2), Test(3,4))
val testDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(testList)

// define the hasColumn function
def hasColumn(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, colName: String) = df.columns.contains(colName)

// then you can just use it on the DF with a given column name
hasColumn(testDF, "a")  // <-- true
hasColumn(testDF, "c")  // <-- false
```

Alternatively you can define an implicit class using the pimp my library pattern so that the hasColumn method is available on your dataframes directly

```
implicit class DataFrameImprovements(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) {
    def hasColumn(colName: String) = df.columns.contains(colName)
}
```

Then you can use it as:

```
testDF.hasColumn("a") // <-- true
testDF.hasColumn("c") // <-- false
```

Comment: This doesn't work with the nested columns. from json `{"a":{"b":1,"c":0}}`

Answer (score 11):

`Try` is not optimal as the it will evaluate the expression inside `Try` before it takes the decision.

For large data sets, use the below in `Scala`:

```
df.schema.fieldNames.contains("column_name")
```

Comment: I agree `Try` is not optimal. What I do is: I create a column with the array of fields and then test with `array_contains`:
`val fields = df.schema.fieldNames; df.withColumn("fields",lit(fields)).withColumn("has_column", when(array_contains($"fields","field1"),lit(true)))`
```

Answer (score 8):

For those who stumble across this looking for a Python solution, I use:

```
if 'column_name_to_check' in df.columns:
    # do something
```

When I tried @Jai Prakash's answer of `df.columns.contains('column-name-to-check')` using Python, I got `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'contains'`.

Comment: Does this way of checking col in the data-frame slow down the spark processing?

Comment: @vasista Can you help me better understand your question? Is there some other approach against which you want to compare performance?

Answer (score 4):

Your other option for this would be to do some array manipulation (in this case an `intersect`) on the `df.columns` and your `potential_columns`.

```
// Loading some data (so you can just copy & paste right into spark-shell)
case class Document( a: String, b: String, c: String)
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(Document("a", "b", "c")), 2).toDF

// The columns we want to extract
val potential_columns = Seq("b", "c", "d")

// Get the intersect of the potential columns and the actual columns, 
// we turn the array of strings into column objects
// Finally turn the result into a vararg (: _*)
df.select(potential_columns.intersect(df.columns).map(df(_)): _*).show
```

Alas this will not work for you inner object scenario above. You will need to look at the schema for that.

I'm going to change your `potential_columns` to fully qualified column names

```
val potential_columns = Seq("a.b", "a.c", "a.d")

// Our object model
case class Document( a: String, b: String, c: String)
case class Document2( a: Document, b: String, c: String)

// And some data...
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(Document2(Document("a", "b", "c"), "c2")), 2).toDF

// We go through each of the fields in the schema.
// For StructTypes we return an array of parentName.fieldName
// For everything else we return an array containing just the field name
// We then flatten the complete list of field names
// Then we intersect that with our potential_columns leaving us just a list of column we want
// we turn the array of strings into column objects
// Finally turn the result into a vararg (: _*)
df.select(df.schema.map(a => a.dataType match { case s : org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType => s.fieldNames.map(x => a.name + "." + x) case _ => Array(a.name) }).flatMap(x => x).intersect(potential_columns).map(df(_)) : _*).show
```

This only goes one level deep, so to make it generic you would have to do more work.

Answer (score 2):

in pyspark you can simply run

> 'field' in df.columns

Answer (score 1):

If you shred your json using a schema definition when you load it then you don't need to check for the column. if it's not in the json source it will appear as a null column.

```
        val schemaJson = """
  {
      "type": "struct",
      "fields": [
          {
            "name": field1
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true,
            "metadata": {}
          },
          {
            "name": field2
            "type": "string",
            "nullable": true,
            "metadata": {}
          }
      ]
  }
        """
    val schema = DataType.fromJson(schemaJson).asInstanceOf[StructType]

    val djson = sqlContext.read
    .schema(schema )
    .option("badRecordsPath", readExceptionPath)
    .json(dataPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def hasColumn(df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame, colName: String) =
  Try(df.select(colName)).isSuccess
```

Use the above mentioned function to check the existence of column including nested column name.

Answer (score 0):

In PySpark, df.columns gives you a list of columns in the dataframe, so 
"colName" in df.columns 
would return a True or False. Give a try on that. Good luck!

Comment: df1.columns displays ['bankData', 'reference', 'submissionTime']; but df1['bankData']['userAddress'].columns displays Column<'bankData[userAddress][columns]'>, doesnt show me the struct, am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For nested columns you can use

```
df.schema.simpleString().find('column_name')
```

Comment: This does not seem reliable to me if you have a Column named similarly to the extraneous text in the Schema string.