# Check if an element is present in a StructType in a Spark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have in python a Spark DataFrame with nested columns, and I have the path `a.b.c`, and want to check if there is a nested column after **c** called **d**, so if `a.b.c.d` exists.

Simply checking `df.columns['a']['b']['c']['d']` or `df.columns['a.b.c.d']` doesn't seem to work, so I found that the `df.schema` function can be used.
So I just iterate through e.g.:

```
y = df.schema['a'].dataType['b'].dataType['c'].dataType
```

and then should normally check if **d** is in **y**.

The way I did it is simply try `y['d']`, and if it fails, then it doesn't exist.
But I don't think using **try** is the best way.

So I tried checking `if 'd' in y`, but apparently this doesn't work, although retrieving the element `y['d']` works if it exists.

The type of y is `StructType(List(StructField(d,StringType,true),...other columns))`

So I don't really know how to properly check if d is in y. Why can't I directly check `if 'd' in y` when I can retrieve `y['d']`? Can anyone help? I'm also new in python, but I can't find or think of another solution.

Comment: I think using `in` doesn't work because of the data type of `schema` which is a `StructType`, which according to documentation contains a list of `StructField`. So you are trying to check if string 'd' is in a list of `StructField`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I detect if a spark dataframe has a column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904136/how-do-i-detect-if-a-spark-dataframe-has-a-column)

Comment: Yes, I though of that, but I still don't understand how come then retrieving `y['d']` works. So is there no simple way to check for this, except with `try`? The referenced post is not very helpful, because in python there is no quick `Try` as an option function (as far as I know, and that is the whole thing I am trying to avoid), and there's no solution for nested columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
df.schema.simpleString().find("column_name:")
```

or

```
"column_name:" in df.schema.simpleString()
```

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).