# How to query a does not exist column in a spark sql

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any way to query a does not exist column in a Spark SQL?
I get a list of JSON by spark-streaming , and then , I want to transform this jsons  as a temporary table .So I can use SQL to query for these.
I get a tmp table below:

```
SparkSession ss = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConf).getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> rdd = ss.read().json(rdd);
rdd.registerTempTable("tmp_table");
```

and this table's struct is 'username,passwr,uid,kid'
but when I use SQL to query:

```
ss.sql("select * from tmp_table where xxx=1");
```

"xxx" is a column which does not in this table's column.

How can I do for it ?  I want to get none result when the column does not exist  but no error like this:

> Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot 
>    resolve 'xxx' given input columns

Because of I don't know which column will exist until I really use this data, I can not to specify fix column for it and I only get it SQL condition before.

Besides, I want to configure this SQL condition but not write it in my code. I just want to get a result for "none result " when column doesn't exist,or get a result for "none result or this column is null and so on " when column doesn't exist.

Thank you for your resolution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904136/how-do-i-detect-if-a-spark-dataframe-has-a-column

Comment: what do you mean by `but not write it in my code`? when a simple if else can solve your issue.