# Spark Scala, how to check if nested column is present in dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, schema, parquet

I'm reading a dataframe from parquet file, which has nested columns (`struct`).
How can I check if nested columns are present?

It might be like this

```
+----------------------+
| column1              |
+----------------------+
|{a_id:[1], b_id:[1,2]}|
+----------------------+
```

or like this

```
+---------------------+
| column1             |
+---------------------+
|{a_id:[3,5]}         |
+---------------------+
```

I know, how to check if top-level column is present, as answered here: [How do I detect if a Spark DataFrame has a column](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35904136) :

```
df.schema.fieldNames.contains("column_name")
```

But how can I check for nested column?

Comment: You can use `.printSchema()` to analyze the inferred schema. Also you can convert to a typed `Dataset` by defining `case class myClass(...)` and using `.as[myClass]` to see if it converts successfully.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36332079) explains it. This is most reliable method to check for nested columns.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I detect if a Spark DataFrame has a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904136/how-do-i-detect-if-a-spark-dataframe-has-a-column)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get schema of nested field as struct, and then check if your field is present in field names of it:

```
val index = df.schema.fieldIndex("column1")
val is_b_id_present = df.schema(index).dataType.asInstanceOf[StructType]
                          .fieldNames.contains("b_id")
```