# Check whether nested data exist on parquet scala spark or not?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, parquet

So, I have a parquet file with nested data like this. I want to process in scala using spark:

```
[
  {
    "sheep": {
      "id": 1,
      "data": {
        "age": 1,
        "price": 101
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "sheep": {
      "id": 2,
      "data": {
        "age":2
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "sheep": {
      "id": 3,
    }
  }
]
```

I tried to select the data in DataFrame, and then convert it to `.csv` file

```
def get: DataFrame = {
  sheepDF
    .select(
      $"sheep.id".as("id"),
      $"sheep.data.age".as("age"),
      $"sheep.data.price".as("price")
    )
}
```

Then, it will generate a file like this:

```
--------------------
| id | age | price |
--------------------
| 1  |  1  |  123  |
| 2  |  2  |       |
| 3  |     |       |
--------------------
```

I want the output file like this:

```
--------------------
| id | age | price |
--------------------
| 1  |  1  |  123  |
| 2  |  2  |   0   |
| 3  |     |   0   |
--------------------
```

I've combine `when` using `isNaN` and `isNull` like [this](https://medium.com/@mrpowers/a-tour-of-column-predicate-methods-in-spark-5b1467d53c21) article explain.

```
def get: DataFrame = {
  val priceCol = $"sheep.data.price"

  sheepDF
    .select(
      $"sheep.id".as("id"),
      $"sheep.data.age".as("age"),
      when(priceCol.isNaN, 0).otherwise(priceCol).as("price")
    )
}
```

I also see this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36332079), but I can't find how to use it. Firstly, since I am using `$"sheep.data.price"` with `$`, how can I pass to the `hasColumn` function? And how do I refer to the `df` argument on the `hasColumn` function? Should I be passing `sheepDF`?

Then, when I try to combine `when` with `hasColumn`
I got this error:

```
type mismatch;
 found   : Boolean
 required: org.apache.spark.sql.Column
```

I also try to read what this `$"sheep.data.price"` returns when there is no data found. I try to print it like this:

```
(lit($"sheep.data.price".getClass.toString())).as("coupon"),
```

But, it returns `class org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName`

I know there should be a simpler solution without `Try`. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use col("column").

```
df.select(
    col("sheep.id").as("id"),
    col("sheep.data.age").as("age"), 
    when(col("sheep.data.price").isNull, 0).otherwise(col("sheep.data.price")).as("price")).show
```

The result is:

```
+---+----+-----+
| id| age|price|
+---+----+-----+
|  1|   1|  101|
|  2|   2|    0|
|  3|null|    0|
+---+----+-----+
```

Comment: It's still didn't work for me. It still prints empty, same like I'm using `$`

Comment: I didn't use your dataframe definitions but just directly proceeds from the json data.And, I used `isNull` not `isNAN`. Try my code with sheepDF

Comment: Wow, yeah it apparently works. There's a typo when working your solution. Now it works!