# Check if column exists in Spark Dataframe using Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

According to [How do I detect if a Spark DataFrame has a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904136/how-do-i-detect-if-a-spark-dataframe-has-a-column), there is a function like `df.columns.contains("column-name-to-check")` which can check whether a column exists. I searched around and didn't find similar function in Java Spark. Does anybody know whether there's a similar one in Java?

Answer (score 3):

One of the options:

`Arrays.asList(df.columns()).contains("column-name-to-check")`

Answer (score 1):

In the Java API, `columns` returns `String[]`. Therefore, I guess you can use `java.util.Arrays` (since [Java 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)):

```java
String yourColumn = "columnName";
String[] columns = df.columns();
boolean contains = Arrays.stream(columns).anyMatch(yourColumn::equals);
```