# Create struct field with respecting different rules

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Im creating structure of nested elements . 
Im having difficulties about how to create a nested struct with tests.
Have a look on my code below. I want to add struct:

`(if x2.fields3 == 1 then create struct_1, if x2.fields3==2 create struct_2)`

```
df = df.withColumn("General",
               struct(
                   col("x1.field1").alias("gen1"),
                   col("x1.field2").alias("gen2"),

                   struct(col("x1.field1").alias("gen3.1"),
                   col("x2.field1").alias("gen3.2"),
                   col("x1.field4").alias("gen3.3"),
                   col("x2.field4").alias("gen3.4"),
                   col("x1.field5").alias("gen3.5"),
                   col("x1.field3").alias("gen3.6"),
                   struct(struct(lit('AA').alias("gen3.7.1.1"),
                    lit("BB").alias("gen3.7.1.2")).alias("gen3.7.1")

                         #Add new struct with test 


                         ).alias("gen3.7")).alias("gen3")

                    )).drop('x1','x2')
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `when` with condition:

```
when(col("x2.fields3") == lit(1), struct(...).alias("struct_1"))\
.when(col("x2.fields3") == lit(2), struct(...).alias("struct_2"))
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I didn't undersnat what can I put in the struct(....).

Comment: As you didn't specify what you want in the structs, I just put `...`, just add the columns or literals you want to the structs ;-)

Comment: (when(col("x2.field3") == lit(1), struct(col("x1.field1").alias("index2")).alias("struct_1")))
(when(col("x2.field3") == lit(2), struct(col("x1.field1").alias("Index1")).alias("struct_2")))

Comment: Hi @over, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36332079/1386551) for how to check if column exists.

Comment: Thank you so much but I got error when I tried to run your code lines .

Comment: Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o13564.withColumn.
: org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN (CAST(`x2`.`field3` AS INT) = 1) THEN named_struct('index2', `x1`.`field1`) WHEN (CAST(`x2`.`field3` AS INT) = 2) THEN nam

Comment: your link is using Scala @blachbishop. and as you know am using pyspark

Comment: Below the scala code there is also a python equivalent, please read the answer entirely.

Comment: do you know please why I have this error?@blackbishop