# How do I check if column present in the Spark DataFrame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying a logic to return an empty column if column does not exist in dataframe.

Schema changes very frequent, sometime the whole struct will be missing (`temp1`) or array inside struct will be missing (`suffix`)

Schema looks like this:

```
    root
     |-- id: string (nullable = true)
     |-- temp: array (nullable = true)
     |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- temp1: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- code: string (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- code1: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |-- temp2: struct (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |-- name1: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
     |    |    |    |-- suffix: array (nullable = true)
     |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
     |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

Or like this:

```
     root
      |-- id: string (nullable = true)
      |-- temp: array (nullable = true)
      |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      |    |    |-- temp2: struct (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |-- name1: array (nullable = true)
      |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
      |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
```

When I am trying the below logic for the second schema, getting an exception that Struct not found

```
def has_Column(df: DataFrame, path: String) = Try(df(path)).isSuccess
    
df.withColumn("id", col("id")).
  withColumn("tempLn", explode(col("temp"))).
  withColumn("temp1_code1", when(lit(has_Column(df, "tempLn.temp1.code1")), concat_ws(" ",col("tempLn.temp1.code1"))).otherwise(lit("").cast("string"))).
  withColumn("temp2_suffix", when(lit(has_Column(df, "tempLn.temp2.suffix")), concat_ws(" ",col("tempLn.temp2.suffix"))).otherwise(lit("").cast("string")))
```

Error:

> org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: No such struct field temp1;

Comment: check this out : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904136/how-do-i-detect-if-a-spark-dataframe-has-a-column

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the check the existence outside the select/withColumn... methods. As you reference it in the `then` part of case when expression, Spark tries to resolve it during the analysis of the query.

So you'll need to test like this:

```
if (has_Column(df, "tempLn.temp1.code1"))
   df.withColumn("temp2_suffix", concat_ws(" ",col("tempLn.temp2.suffix")))
else
   df.withColumn("temp2_suffix", lit(""))
```

To do it for multiple columns you can use foldLeft like this:

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("tempLn.temp1.code1", "temp1_code1"),
  ("tempLn.temp2.suffix", "temp2_suffix")
).foldLeft(df) {
  case (acc, (field, newCol)) => {
    if (has_Column(acc, field))
      acc.withColumn(newCol, concat_ws(" ", col(field)))
    else
      acc.withColumn(newCol, lit(""))
  }
}
```