# Check if column exists in Spark when reading files in structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm reading files from HDFS using Spark Structured Streaming API.
but the schema is not fixed. I'm using:

```
 sql.streaming.schemaInference: "true"
```

so the schema might be different for every batch.
So if I try to select rows using:

```
 dataframe.select(columnName)
```

it will complain if the column doesn't exist.
So is there a way to check if the column doesn't exist before selecting it when using structured streaming api?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I detect if a Spark DataFrame has a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35904136/how-do-i-detect-if-a-spark-dataframe-has-a-column)

Comment: the problem with streaming is that the schema change for every batch. 
I think the solution in this question will only work fine for the first batch only.