# Is there any way to retain the state of multiple expandable mat-grid after refresh?

Tags: angular

I have a Mat-Table grid with multiple expanded rows . Now suppose i expand few of the rows . The grid now looks like -

[image]

Now if i do some crud operation on the mat-table and i refresh the page , i want the mat-table to retain its previous form with the rows expanded . But currently it refreshes , and goes back to its collapsed state , which is -

[image]

Is there any way i can retain the expanded state of the grid even after refresh ? Please guide me .

This is the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested?file=app/table-expandable-rows-example.html) for my grid with expanded rows .

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand so much when you say "refresh", so I only can give a few ideas. In all case you need you need store the "elements" expanded.

If when you say "refresh" is refresh the navigator, the only is use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

If you want to say change to another router in your API you need use a service

If you edit the table in the same component you can use a simple array or variable in your component

In general you need store the full user only some that make as "key" -in your stackblitz you has no a "key", so you need use as "key" some like `name+email+phone` so you can has an array with, e.g.

```
[Masonmason@test.com9864785214, Eugeneeugene@test.com8786541234 ]
```

Or a simple variable with the elements separated by, e.g. `~`

```
Masonmason@test.com9864785214~Eugeneeugene@test.com8786541234
```

For this create four functions clearElements, addElement,removeElement and getElements

```
clearElements()
{
   this.expanded=null
}
addElement(element:any)
{
  const expanded=this.expanded?this.expanded.split('~'):[]
  expanded.push(element)
  this.expanded=expanded.join('~')
}
removeElement(element)
{
  this.expanded=expanded.filter(x=>x!=element).join('~')
}
getElements()
{
   return this.expanded.split('~')
}
```

Then, when you get the new data you can recover the elements and llop over your array of data, if the data is in the array is expanded

```
//If you use localstorage
get expanded()
{
    return windows.localstorage.getItem('myApp-expanded')
}
set expanded(value)
{
    windows.localstorage.setItem('myApp-expanded',value)
}

//if you use a service
get expanded()
{
    return this.serviceData.expanded
}
set expanded(value)
{
    this.serviceData.expanded=value
}
//if is a variable simple declare it

expanded:string=null
```

**Update** The code, added a new property to the data "expanded" to the rows expanded. If we are sure that the rows before and after update are the sames we can make some like

```
this.usersData=USERS.map((user,i) => {
  if (
    user.addresses &&
    Array.isArray(user.addresses) &&
    user.addresses.length
  ) {
    return { ...user,expanded:expanded?expanded[i].expanded:false, addresses: 
      user.addresses.map((x,j)=>{
        let expandedAddress=false;
        if (expanded && expanded[i] && expanded[i].addresses)
             expandedAddress=expanded[i].addresses[j].expanded

        return {...x,expanded:expandedAddress}
      }) 
    }
  } else {
    return {...user,addresses:null,expanded:true}
  }
});
this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.usersData);
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
```

See that I make the code simpler using as interface

```
export interface AddressExpanded extends Address {
  expanded:boolean;
}

export interface UserExpanded{
  name: string;
  email: string;
  phone: string;
  expanded:boolean;
  addresses?: AddressExpanded[] ;

}
```

I don't think that makes the address a MatDataTable source means a significance improve in the code -if you're not planning filtered or paginate a data source use a simple array

I forked your stackblitz in [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nested-mat-table-triplenested-qpg9gf?file=app%2Ftable-expandable-rows-example.ts)

Comment: With refresh i meant , suppose there's a update button , and on the click of save button it updates the email suppose . If the rows are expanded and I click on save it is currently , collapses the rows .

Comment: Update answer (see that when we write `(click)="element.expanded = !element?.expanded"` in the .html really we are adding a new "property" to "element"