# Check if Input dataset contains a key or not in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following code as shown below. I need to check if the column `y.lc.eoouh.ci` is present in the input source and populate the column only if present, else it should be NULL.(The key `lc` is also optional)
The code below doesn't seem to work the way it is supposed to as even though `y.lc.eoouch.ci` is present in the input, it evaluates to NULL.

The `has_column` implementation is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36332079/11697394).

```py
df = df_s_a \
            .withColumn("ceci", \
                udf(
                    lambda y : y.lc[-1].eoouh.ci \
                        if has_column(y, 'lc.eoouh.ci') \
                            else None, \
                    StringType()
                   )(col('eh') \
                   ) \
                ) \
            .select(                    
                col('ceci')
            )
df.show()
```

Sample input:

```json
{
 eh: {
   lc: [
      eoouch: {
       ci: "1234ABC"
    }
  ]
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `df[something.path.somewhere]` doesn't work. I'll have to investigate that option a bit.

I've managed to make it work like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType


def has_column(df):
    try:
        df["lc"][0]["eoouch"]["ci"]
        return True
    except KeyError:
        return False


if __name__ == "__main__":

    spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    data = [
        {"eh": {"lc": [{"eoouch": {"ci": "test"}}]}},
        {"eh": {"lc": [{"eoouch": {"as": "test"}}]}},
    ]

    df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
    add_column_udf = F.udf(
        lambda y: y if has_column(y) else None,
        StringType(),
    )
    df = df.withColumn("ceci", add_column_udf(F.col("eh")))
```

Result:

```
+----------------------------------+-------------------------+                  
|eh                                |ceci                     |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------+
|{lc -> [{eoouch -> {ci -> test}}]}|{lc=[{eoouch={ci=test}}]}|
|{lc -> [{eoouch -> {as -> test}}]}|null                     |
+----------------------------------+-------------------------+
```

It's not perfect since it's not a general solution for column name but it could be easily generalized since it works on a `dict` object.